# How to disable ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup from inlining small images?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-dom, react-dom-server

My React app is currently using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` to generate HTML emails.

The problem I'm having with `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` is that it converts small images (under 12kb) from a image src URL to an inline image. This is resulting in images having attachments which is undesirable.

How can I configure ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup to not inline small images under (12kb)?

Answer (score 1):

By the tags i assume you are using `create-react-app`. Under the hood it [uses](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/706b319633a59e1e0d58f1bb957e9d30d172f9d8/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L208-L215) `url-loader` which inlines images smaller than 10kb. You can eject webpack config and either increase the threshold or replace `url-loader` with `file-loader`.

---

#### Ways to do it without ejecting

- You can put them in a [public folder](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder) and use them from there. Instead of importing the file it can be referenced like that: `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />`
- Specify file loader directly in the import. I.e. instead of `import imageUrl from './image.png';` use `import imageUrl from '!!file!./image.png';`. Double exclamation points at the start are used to ignore loaders from webpack config and `file!` means use file-loader, which doesn't do inlining.

Comment: I am using create-react-app -- is there a way to do this without ejecting?